# bootstrap carousel does not switch between slides when used in reactjs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have the following reactjs component which tries to load a bootstrap carousel. But the carousel navigations does not work and only the first image is shown. I have verified that the second and third images exist (by making them the first image) in the correct path too.

Is there something we need to add to use bootstrap carousel on reactjs, as carousel is a plugin in bootstrap ? Rest of the bootstrap classes (like btn, label, etc.) work flawless in the rest of the react components.

The source:

```
import React from 'react'

class LandingPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div id="myCarousel" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol className="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" className="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>

          <div className="carousel-inner">

            <div className="item active">
              <img src={require("../images/pexels-photo-112640.jpeg")} alt="Chicago" className="landing-page-image" />

              <div className="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Chicago</h3>
                <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="item">
              <img src={require("../images/pexels-photo-110473.jpeg")} alt="Los Angeles" className="landing-page-image" />

              <div className="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
                <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="item">
              <img src={require("../images/pexels-photo.jpg")} alt="New York" className="landing-page-image" />
              <div className="carousel-caption">
                <h3>New York</h3>
                <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <a className="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a className="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LandingPage
```

The import for bootstrap in my index.js is, as follows:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'
```

The tutorial where the carousel code is copied from (and 'class' changed to 'className') is available at: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem arises because `Bootstrap` has a `Javascript` component as well which clashes with `React`. You can use `Bootstrap's` `CSS` functions fine (like the grid system with `col-md-*`, the `btn`, `label` classes you are mentioning etc) but the `Javascript` part won't work. And the `Carousel` requires the `Javascript` part of `Bootstrap` (Other `Bootstrap` components that won't work are `Modal`, `Navbar` etc).

To resolve this you should use `React-Bootstrap` - `Bootstrap` components written in `React` - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/.

Here is the section for carousels - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using react-bootstrap because it is not even 1.0 yet and I do not want it in a project in production whose APIs may change :( Is there no other way to import the js dependencies of bootstrap into (is it just jquery or something else too ?) my react app ?

Comment: Not directly as `Bootstrap` modifies the `DOM` directly while `React` keeps changing the `DOM` according to the `state` so this means the when `Bootstrap` initializes it won't even be able to latch up to the components as the `React` app is still being `mounted`. Since you just need the `Carousel` you can build your own `React` component with similar features or you can use other 3rd party `React` carousel components - https://github.com/akiran/react-slick and https://github.com/FormidableLabs/nuka-carousel are something that came up in a simple Google search

Comment: yes, I came across them when I searched but I am a bit reluctant to use libraries which may end up being unmaintained. Thanks.

Comment: Same issue occuring for me.Carousel sliding is working only once.When you move to another component and come back it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

### In your way needed `bootstrap js` and it's work use jquery.

#### It's a better way to solve your problem. and avoid the jquery script to react-bootstrap on the react way. here the example: [carousel/#example](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/carousel/#example)

```
<Carousel>
  <Carousel.Item>
   <img src={require("../images/pexels-photo-112640.jpeg")} alt="Chicago" className="landing-page-image" />
    <Carousel.Caption>
       <h3>New York</h3>
       <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>

  <Carousel.Item>
    // your slide image 
    <Carousel.Caption>
       //....... your content
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
```

note: `<Carousel>` instant create `.carousel` element and  `Carousel.Item` to 'carousel-item'

#### Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out a workaround for this issue, if you don't want to install "React-Bootstrap" package this is going to help you.

Keep your carousel html and add this on your header/nav component.
The code will execute after rendering the site and wait 5 sec until the click is activated. Make sure to import  "useEffect"

```
  useEffect(() => {
   setTimeout(function () {
   document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-control-next-icon')[0].click();
  }, 5000); }, [])
```

Hope this helps